# If a KParameter.isOptional = true, how can I get the default value?

Tags: kotlin, reflect

**My class:**

```
data class TestMockModel(val age: Int = 3)
```

How can I get the age's default value by age's KParameter?

**such**

```
val ageKParameter = TestMockModel::class.parameters[0]
```

How can I get the default value by ageKParameter

Comment: TestMockModel().age

Comment: @bambam It's work, but how to get age by KParameter?